# Which coordinate system is data frame set to if first layer has no spatial reference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I have added a layer without spatial reference to a Blank Map document.

Which coordinate system is the data frame set to?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good question should include a degree of research and attempt.  What happened when you tried adding your own no spatial referenced layer to ArcMap?

Answer (score 4):

To determine this just add a shapefile with no PRJ file to a Blank Map, and then check the Coordinate System tab of the Properties for the Layers data frame to see that it is:

> No coordinate system.

[image]